# "System.Runtime.Serialization'. Are you missing an assembly reference?" after adding web reference

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, web-reference

I have an iOS/Android Xamarin project that share a PCL project.

I have added a web reference to the PCL via ASMX as per [Xamarin's Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#asmx). The tutorial doesn't say how to get to the "Add Web Reference" window, but we found it by right-clicking our PCL project and going to `Add->Web Reference`.

On adding the web reference I get a roughly 500 line Reference.cs file that is added to the PCL.

However, on compilation, either iOS or Android, I am given several of these errors:

> Reference.cs(74,74): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `IExtensibleDataObject' does not exist in the namespace`System.Runtime.Serialization'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (MyProject)

It is clear that I need to add the `System.Runtime.Serialization` assembly reference. However I cannot figure out how to do this and I have spent hours looking for documentation or any relevant solution. Most posts questions appear tangental at best.

This [forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6369/system-runtime-serialization-not-automatically-included-while-adding-web-reference) references this issue, but give no solution other than it was supposedly “fixed” three years ago.

Now the aforementioned tutorial references an "Add References…" dialog box for adding the `System.Web.Services.dll` if you use "Add files" to add the proxy. However, I cannot find this dialog anywhere in the IDE.

I did find "Edit References" when right-clicking on references. This produced a window with these tabs:

[image]

Guessing that the assembly needs to be added here I search for it, but find nothing. Apparently there is no way to add assemblies that are packaged with the IDE, you're expected to "just know" where to find them. Searching for documentation proves fruitless.

Via one of the sample project, I was able to locate the .dll file at `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` and manually add it via the .NET Assembly tab.

A colleague tried adding the reference via NuGet as well.

Unfortunately the compile errors remain after attempting either approach.

Also, of note, it appears that the ToDoASMX example project nor the folder containing the `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` have any references to the `System.Web.Services.dll` that the tutorial mentions.

Comment: What version of C# are you running?

Comment: @AlexKrupka All three projects say "default" for the C# version. I am using Xamarin Studio Community 6.0.2 (build 73)  I'm not sure what the IDE's default is, but looks like version 6 is supported.

Comment: How are you adding the service reference? Are you creating a proxy? Are you just right clicking and "Add Web Service"? Can you put reproduction steps into your question so we can investigate further?

Comment: Thank you, @JonDouglas for reaching out. I've added additional detail to the question.

Comment: I believe these docs are referring to using them in `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android`(At least for the `.asmx` docs). You can get to `System.Runtime.Serialization` via right clicking `References` in your `Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android` project, Going to `Edit References`, then going to the `All` tab which it should be listed under the `BCL` (Base Class LIbrary).

You may need to go the route of using a `Interface` based pattern within your PCL to call the respective native web service instead. You could also try wrapping your .asmx into a REST service and using `HttpClient` as well.

Comment: Seeing this sample project shows the `Interface` based pattern described above using `ISoapService` in the PCL and implementing in the native projects. You will see each project (Droid/iOS) have the `Web Reference` in them. The PCL is purely invoking the code.

Comment: Gotcha. We'll give that a try. Thank you. It is very strange to me that in order to use a PCL you would have to duplicate effort and code, even if it is generated, like this.

Comment: It's more of a limitation of using `.asmx` given the framework built around them. Using `WCF` or `REST` have better options for consuming directly from a PCL. However note that PCLs are going to be replaced by `NetStandard` libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these docs are referring to using them in `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android`(At least for the `.asmx` docs). You can get to `System.Runtime.Serialization`via right clicking `References` in your `Xamarin.iOS`/ `Xamarin.Android` project, Going to `Edit References`, then going to the `All` tab which it should be listed under the `BCL (Base Class LIbrary)`. You may need to go the route of using an `Interface` based pattern within your `PCL` to call the respective native web service instead. You could also try wrapping your `.asmx` into a `REST service` and using `HttpClient` as well.

Seeing this sample project(https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoASMX/) shows the `Interface` based pattern described above using `ISoapService` in the `PCL` and implementing in the native projects. You will see each project (`Droid/iOS`) have the `Web Reference` in them. The PCL is purely invoking the code.

It's more of a limitation of using `.asmx` given the framework built around them. Using `WCF` or `REST` have better options for consuming directly from a PCL. However note that PCLs are going to be replaced by `NetStandard` library flavor.